# How to restore all user running apps after system reset?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, savestate

I am developing android launcher and I want to save state of all currently running apps(audio player, calendar e.t.c), before reset device.After reset, relaunch all previously running apps in their previous states and the same order as before. For example: launch audio player and seting it on the same song and same position of playing, and calendar on the same selected day.

I was playing around with ActivityManager. For example, getting all running processes:

```
ActivityManager activitymanager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

rnPrc = activitymanager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

but did not find anything that would fit my purposes.

I am wondering, is it possible to get something like memory snapshot or state of currently running apps in android, for saving it in sqlite db? If it is, how then, use it to restore user apps?

I will be grateful for any hint.

Comment: 1) you can't get all running processes (since some Android version like 6.0). 2) You can't get their *states*, as if you could - you could extract private information from them. For example, the web browser - if you could get it's *state* (e. g. opened tabs' URLS), you would be able to get the user's private info, as you shouldn't be able to know which web sites is the user browsing. 3) You can't restore those states (in case if you could even get them) as there is no such API in Android. So basically your idea is 99% impossible to implement.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, that's a sad to hear that:( What about something like system memory snapshot or dump without personal info?

Comment: it should be possible, but only with root access, which is not an option unless you want to distribute your apps only among rooted devices, or embed it into some firmware as a system app.